# access elements of datagrid view

Tags: c#

```
 string s = dataGridView1[0, 0].ToString();
                string s2 = dataGridView1[0, 1].ToString();
```

I used the above method to access elements of datagridview.
but i'm getting only these values in 's' and 's2'
"DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=0 }"

"DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=1 }"

but the values in datagrid are '1','hello'.
how can i access it.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString();
string s2 = dataGridView1[0, 1].Value.ToString();
```

You'll notice that when you index into the DGV you get an instance of the DataGridViewTextBoxCell class.  It does overload the ToString method, but not in the way you hoped/expected.

So you must get the value contained within this instance, then call ToString on it.

Comment: Yes but which number is the column index and which is the row index?

Is it dataGridView[row, column] or is it dataGridView[column, row] ?

Comment: @advocate row, col. Always.  Everywhere.

Comment: What's the difference between this notation and DataGridViews.Rows[row].Cells[column].Value ?

Comment: @advocate shorthand.  By my memory.  Use what works, by all means.